# When I am trying to install @microsoft/generator-sharepoint, I get below error. Kindly note that my node version is v10.6.0 and npm version is 6.2.0

Tags: spfx

[image]i dont know how to install this help me if someone can

i am getting 404 error
@microsoft/generator-sharepoint, I get below error. Kindly note that my node version is v10.6.0 and npm version is 6.2.0

Comment: I checked the compatible versions and installed accordingly and after that i created the account in npm and then created the new token.

Comment: then i tried to login in to npm in the same windows powershell and tried the npm install -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint

Comment: I created the token and tried its still the same error

Comment: I dont know where i am doing the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- close the current power shell
- open windows power shell
- check the versions if nodes js and npm are compatible
- Check the versions at the url (https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/)
- Check the versions with the command npm -v
- check the node version with node -v
- Try to update or degrade the versions by using the command  npm install -g npm@6(for 6th verion) keep this in sync with the node js
- after that follow the steps
- npm install -g yo gulp
- npm install -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint

thats it all it is set